# How to retrieve build attachment from VSTS release summary tab

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to retrieve a build attachment attached using (##vso[task.addattachment]value) from release summary page (ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-summary-tab). Please point me to any references to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: @Daniel Mann: I have referred REST API Reference for VS Team Services, it doesn't contain required details.

Comment: What is the detailed issue you meet?

Comment: @Eddie: I have attached a file to the build using ##vso[task.addattachment]value command from my build task. Now I need to retrieve this file from the **release summary** tab (ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-summary-tab) to extract data from the attachment and display in my custom release summary tab. Is it possble to do this through VSTS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do followings things to get this:

1.Get the related build id of the release via [getConfiguration()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_getConfiguration):

```
var c = VSS.getConfiguration();
c.onReleaseChanged(function (release) {
release.artifacts.forEach(function (art) {
var buildid = art.definitionReference.version.id;
});
});
```

2.Use the build ID you get in previous step to get the detailed build information via [getBuild()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_2#getBuild). And then you can get the planid from the build information.

3.Use the planid to get the uploaded file via [getPlanAttachments()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/distributedtask/taskrestclient/taskhttpclient2_2#getPlanAttachments).

Comment: @ Eddie, Thanks Eddie, these steps worked and I was able to retrieve the attachment.

Comment: Eddie, I have noticed that build plan is getting null for recent releases, I haven't done any code changes in this area which worked perfectly in last few weeks, I have upgraded the TFS to 2015.3, any idea about this issue?
 
buildClient.getBuild(buildId).then((buildData) => {
if (**buildData.plans**.length === 1) {}

Thanks

Comment: @BandR So this issue occurs after upgrading to 2015.3?

Comment: It seems TFS version in not the issue, I used **buildData.orchestrationPlan.planId** instead of **buildData.plans[x].planId** and now it's working in both VSTS and TFS 2015 environments. Do you think this change is valid?
Thanks-

Comment: We came across following issue when displaying data in release summary tab in following scenario, Will you be able to help us on this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451462/populate-data-in-to-vsts-release-summary-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1